# Using of include in accessing file from different directory

Tags: php, file, directory, include, filepath

I've been wondering this lately, why is my files on pages>role_pages>admin display the bootstrap links from the includes>links files, all the pages in my admin folder has design, my login page haven't.

I guess, the problem is in the '..' of my includes in login.php and admin_dashboard.php

Can someone help me on how to access the files from the links folder from any layers of folder?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is not clear to me: *"why is my files on pages>role_pages>admin display the bootstrap links from the includes>links files"* ---> because there is an *include* of course. Remove it if you do not want to include this file.

Comment: For the relevant code, post it as text, not only as an image. You can do an excerpt. For the directory structure, please do as well, e.g. symbolize the relevant parts in a code-block.

Comment: how can i access includes a header includes that contains script that a particular path from a file with a different layers of directory?

Comment: I can't explain my problem... but https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEczo1pLobo&t=30s , hope someone understand me